# How to limit how many characters in input boxes Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hi so I wanna limit the texts inside a rectangle and if the text surpasses the rectangle's dimension then it reduces itself to fit in. I use class to make the code easier to read and easier to add more input boxes. When I run the code, there should be different input boxes in which I can edit the text in and if the text is too long, it reduces itself( lastest character) to fit in the box. But when I run the code, the text can go over the rectangle for 1 character and for any letter after that, it deletes a whole chunk of text. Here is the code.

''' `python`

```
import pygame
import datetime

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.font.init()

# Note
finish = 0
leftover = 16

# Font
numb_font = pygame.font.Font('dogicapixelbold.ttf', 14)
text_font = pygame.font.Font('dogicapixelbold.ttf', 16)

color = (233, 248, 215)
active = False

# screen resolution
Width = 800
Height = 600
bg = pygame.image.load('opennote.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height))

# Time
time_box = pygame.Rect(250, 63, 50, 30)
date_box = pygame.Rect(221, 27, 50, 30)
# boxes numb
leftover_box = pygame.Rect(265, 105, 30, 30)
finish_box = pygame.Rect(325, 105, 30, 30)


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = text_font.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = text_font.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+10))
        # Blit the rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)

    def update(self):
        # Limit character
        if self.txt_surface.get_width() > self.rect.w:
            self.text = self.text[:-1]


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = InputBox(115, 170, 250, 36)
    input_box2 = InputBox(115, 224, 250, 36)
    input_box3 = InputBox(115, 278, 250, 36)
    input_box4 = InputBox(115, 333, 250, 36)
    input_box5 = InputBox(115, 386, 250, 36)
    input_box6 = InputBox(115, 440, 250, 36)
    input_box7 = InputBox(115, 494, 250, 36)
    input_boxes = [input_box1, input_box2, input_box3, input_box4, input_box5, input_box6, input_box7]
    done = False

    while not done:
        # Background
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date_now = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)
            # Real Time
            # Date
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', date_box, -1)
        datebox_surface = numb_font.render(date_now, True, color)
        screen.blit(datebox_surface, (date_box.x + 5, date_box.y + 5))
        # Time
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', time_box, -1)
        timebox_surface = numb_font.render(time_now, True, color)
        screen.blit(timebox_surface, (time_box.x + 5, time_box.y + 5))

        # finish &Leftover
        # finish box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', finish_box, -1)
        finishbox_surface = numb_font.render(str(finish), True, color)
        screen.blit(finishbox_surface, finish_box)
        # Leftover box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', leftover_box, -1)
        leftover_box_surface = numb_font.render(str(leftover), True, color)
        screen.blit(leftover_box_surface, leftover_box)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

'''

But when the letter outside the rect's width, it deletes a whole bunch of text not just the letter that outside the width.

Comment: You didn't provide a possible testing point and therefore we can't really help you :/

Comment: I updated the code there :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your update and re-render contents.

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if self.active:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print(self.text)
                self.text = ''
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                self.text = self.text[:-1]
            else:
                self.text += event.unicode
                # Limit characters           -20 for border width
                if self.txt_surface.get_width() > self.rect.w -20:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]

def draw(self, screen):
    # Blit the text.
    screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+10))
    # Blit the rect.
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)

def update(self):
    # Re-render the text.
    self.txt_surface = text_font.render(self.text, True, self.color)
```

---

---

**Edit:**  oh, it's 3am;  I'm just about asleep by now, if I missed posting something that was edited I don't remember.  Had to swap out the background for a plain black rectangle and blit that in just for testing, but I know for certain it runs OK here.  Downloaded same font and everything.  This is what it looks like.

[image: 3am]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
import datetime

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.font.init()

# Note
finish = 0
leftover = 16

# Font
numb_font = pygame.font.Font('dogicapixelbold.ttf', 14)
text_font = pygame.font.Font('dogicapixelbold.ttf', 16)

color = (233, 248, 215)
active = False

# screen resolution
Width = 800
Height = 600
bg = pygame .Surface( [Width,  Height] )
pygame .draw .rect( bg,  (0, 0, 0),  [0,  0,  Width,  Height] )
##  bg = pygame.image.load('opennote.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height))

# Time
time_box = pygame.Rect(250, 63, 50, 30)
date_box = pygame.Rect(221, 27, 50, 30)
# boxes numb
leftover_box = pygame.Rect(265, 105, 30, 30)
finish_box = pygame.Rect(325, 105, 30, 30)


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = text_font.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                    # Limit characters           -20 for border width
                    if self.txt_surface.get_width() > self.rect.w -20:
                        self.text = self.text[:-1]

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+10))
        # Blit the rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)

    def update(self):
        # Re-render the text.
        self.txt_surface = text_font.render(self.text, True, self.color)


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = InputBox(115, 170, 250, 36)
    input_box2 = InputBox(115, 224, 250, 36)
    input_box3 = InputBox(115, 278, 250, 36)
    input_box4 = InputBox(115, 333, 250, 36)
    input_box5 = InputBox(115, 386, 250, 36)
    input_box6 = InputBox(115, 440, 250, 36)
    input_box7 = InputBox(115, 494, 250, 36)
    input_boxes = [input_box1, input_box2, input_box3, input_box4, input_box5, input_box6, input_box7]
    done = False

    while not done:
        # Background
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date_now = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)
            # Real Time
            # Date
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', date_box, -1)
        datebox_surface = numb_font.render(date_now, True, color)
        screen.blit(datebox_surface, (date_box.x + 5, date_box.y + 5))
        # Time
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', time_box, -1)
        timebox_surface = numb_font.render(time_now, True, color)
        screen.blit(timebox_surface, (time_box.x + 5, time_box.y + 5))

        # finish &Leftover
        # finish box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', finish_box, -1)
        finishbox_surface = numb_font.render(str(finish), True, color)
        screen.blit(finishbox_surface, finish_box)
        # Leftover box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', leftover_box, -1)
        leftover_box_surface = numb_font.render(str(leftover), True, color)
        screen.blit(leftover_box_surface, leftover_box)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi, It still eats up a bunch of text when it touches the border tho

Comment: Pretty sure all that was changed was flipping those lines `# Limit characters` with `# Re-render the text.`.  It was eating characters before that.  You can try it with that solid background surface and see if that has any effect on it.